# Test for significant differences among multiple group

Tags: anova

I am not sure whether a test for something like this exists. So I have multiple groups 1,2,3,4.... In each group there are many measurement values.

```
Group      Values
1          [1,293 ,8, 2, 52, 23, 5]
2          [2]
3          [43, 523, 2, 5]
....
```

What I am trying to do is to see whether it makes sense take the average of each group and use it for reporting, instead of reporting all measurements of all groups, which are too many.

I am thinking about doing multiple ANOVA random effect tests, one for each group, and correct for multiple testings. Then I will see how many test we fail to reject the null, the make the decision from there.

I wonder whether there is a better way to tackle this kind of problem. Ideally I am looking to do 1 single test so that it is more straightforward to reach a decision, instead of multiple tests.

I use random effect model/test because in the future we will have more group and each group can have more values in the future.

Comment: Hi, Nancy. Welcome to Cross Validated. Why do you think ANOVA won't be good for that? Moreover, prior applying ANOVA, are you sure the assumptions of ANOVA have been met?

Comment: What exactly is the aim? Test group means equality? If so ANOVA is ok. IF you are worried about normality use permutation or bootstrap.

Comment: The aim is to see whether there is significant variations in the measurement values in groups. Ideally I am looking to do 1 single test so that it is more straightforward to reach a decision, instead of multiple tests